# ArcGIS Javascript API - How to submit a defect?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, error

I would like to know the best way to notify ESRI of a possible defect in the JSAPI and gis.stackexchange seems like the best mechanism for doing so ([Derek](http://twitter.com/#!/derekswingley) reads it and fixes it).  That being said, what is the *proper* way to notify ESRI of a defect?

The defect in this case is posted on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2PhHG/) and can be seen by placing the mouse over the map.  Notice the onMouseMove event continuously fires.  This required a workaround on my part because I was using the onMouseMove event to re-project (esri.config.defaults.geometryService.project) coordinates and if the user left the mouse over the map it was eating up bandwidth.

Documentation states:

> Fires any time the mouse pointer moves over the map region. A common
>   use for this event is to show the current x,y coordinate of the map as
>   the user moves the mouse pointer.

Hence the claim that this is a defect.  This is true in 2.8 and 2.9 (beta)

Comment: You might want to try posting the error on the java api script forum.  I believe ESRI developers check that site.  http://forums.arcgis.com/forums/15-ArcGIS-API-for-JavaScript

Comment: I'm not seeing this error on IE, Chrome, or Firefox. The counter does not change if I don't move the mouse.

Comment: The most important thing to do to report a bug is to have a repro case (which you've done, thank you). The official channel to report a is through support:  http://support.esri.com/en/webform/support/customerId/5753/chat/false (you'll need to be logged into your Esri global account). That being said, in looking at your jsfiddle, I see the same thing as kenbuja– the onMouseMove event only fires when I move the mouse. If the mouse is not moving, no event is fired.

Comment: just as an aside, You ideally shouldn't project using a geometry service on Mouse Move. The service call can take time, if the client is on a slow connection and would get delayed results. In addition, every time the mouse moves over the map, requests will be sent, thus clogging the connection.

Comment: Devdatta - actual code was buffering with a 2500ms delay - is a way to re-projection within JSAPI that I'm not aware of (I know proj4js can do this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important thing to do to report a bug is to have a repro case (which you've done, thank you).

The official channel to report a is through support: http://support.esri.com/en/webform/support/customerId/5753/chat/false (you'll need to be logged into your Esri global account).

That being said, looking at your jsfiddle, I see the same thing as kenbuja– the onMouseMove event only fires when I move the mouse. If the mouse is not moving, no event is fired.