# S-JTSK projected incorrectly in JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, coordinate-system, arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder, geometry-service

I use a method based on the ["project a point"](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/util_project.html) sample to project points from S-JTSK (wkid 102067) to Web Mercator (wkid 102100) and they are ~100m away from their correct position. This happens when I convert them to WGS84 (wkid 4326) as well. Points in other coordinate systems are projected correctly. I tried to use another geometry server, but the problem is obviously not there. [Explicitly setting the transformation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/projectparameters-amd.html#transformation) didn't change anything and [setting forward transformation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/65902/12768) is not suitable for projected to projected SRS. When transforming to WGS84, I end in the Atlantic and the point even doesn't draw there. I tried to use WGS84 as an intermediate step, but the final result is the same.

My code:

```
reprojectStart: function (point)    {
    var sr = new esri.SpatialReference({ 
         wkid: thisDijit.map.spatialReference.wkid 
    });
    var gsvc = new GeometryService("https://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

    var params = new ProjectParameters();
    params.geometries = [ point ];
    params.outSR = new SpatialReference(102100);
    params.transformForward = true;
    var def = gsvc.project(params, function(projectedPoints) {
        var pt = projectedPoints[0];
        point.x = pt.x;
        point.y = pt.y;
        point.spatialReference = pt.spatialReference;
    });
    def.then(function(results){
        return this.anotherMethod(point);
    });
}
```

The only workaround I know now is to either avoid S-JTSK or have both map and the points in it.

I wonder whether it is a bug ("coordinate system not fully supported") and I should [report it to ESRI](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/24527/12768), or if I have some error in my code. Btw. it's a Web AppBuilder custom widget, so it's possible that it works otherwise but clashes with something in WAB.

EDIT: Transformation `wkid`s I've tried: 1623,1625, 4827, 4829 and 5239. @mkennedy's comment encouraged me to try them again and I found the transformation is not being set correctly. `params.transformation.wkid` causes `params.transformation not defined` error. `params.transformation = {wkid:5239}` makes an object, but AFAIK true `transformation` object should have more attributes than just `wkid`. Other `ProjectParameters` attributes are correct. So the question basically changes to **how to set the transform parameter when the way in the official example doesn't work?**

EDIT2: I started examinating another way, through [proj4js](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/85734/12768). However, I [face some problems while making it work](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/188130/12768).

Comment: I think you need to set an actual transformation using params.transformation = 5239. If that wkid doesn't work, try 1623. See https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/util_coordinate_converter.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "I tried to use another geometry server, but the problem is obviously not there", do you mean it works with other GeometryServices but not the one hosted on tasks.arcgisonline.com?

Either way, https://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer is an old server (10.0) that you probably shouldn't be using. The sample you link to has been updated to use a newer server - see the code in https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/util_project.html. (I notice that the sample description still mention the old task server, so ignore that).

Comment: I tried our geometry server, which didn't help. I'll find out its version on Monday; if it's not new enough, I'll try another, new geometry server.

Comment: I don't know why the previous test failed, but now I loaded our 10.2.1 geometry service and the projection is accurate now.